# How to create a WCF SOAP web service to find Distance and Direction between two addresses using ArcGIS Online services

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, soap, wcf

I need to create a WCF SOAP service to find out Distance and Direction between two given addresses. I have to use ArcGIS online service for the same.

Can you please help me out by providing any sample.